# info about <input id="inp" multiple=""...>

Tags: file, input, file-io

I wanted to know what attributes are available to work with for the multiple file input tag, such as:
    `<input multiple="" type="file" id="inp" name="inp[]">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that some nice js to work to get the filenames, but seems jQuery will have to catch up? I do not get the depth of attributes from jQ that I get from document.
     var myInp=jQ 1.7.2 $("#inp");
     var myInp=document.getElementById("inp");
From jQ I only got the first file, while from document.gEBI() the rest of the info about the multiple files selected was available. What I found is there is a files property
inp.files
which is an object having a File object for each of the files, a length property whose value is the file count, and an item method:
    **0 [object File]**
    ... //iterating to the (n-1)th file count
    **n [object File]**
    **length** m //m being the number of files
    **item function item(){[native code]}**

Digging deeper, for the first file:
    inp.files.item(0)
I found that item holds properties and methods for each file:

1) **size** 
2) **type** 
3) **slice function slice(){[native code]}** 
4) **mozSlice function mozSlice(){[native code]}** 
5) **name** 
6) **mozFullPath**

I have not found this information anywhere else. I hope it helps you :)